# Autowire symfony CacheInterface depending on environment

Tags: php, symfony, caching, autowired, psr-6

I am trying to use different cache system on my environments. I would like to have, for example, `Filesystem` for **dev** and `memcached` for **prod**.

I am using **symfony 3.3.10**.

To achieve this, I would like to autowire the *CacheInterface* as follow:

```
use Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface;

class Api {

    public function __construct(CacheInterface $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}
```

Here are my configuration files:

**config_dev.yml**:

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.filesystem
```

**config_prod.yml**:

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.memcached
        ...
```

Here is the error I get:
[image]

The error disappears when the *FilesystemCache* is declared as a service:

```
services:
    Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache: ~
```

But now I cannot have another cache system for the **test** environment like *NullCache*. In fact, I have to declare only one service inheriting from *CacheInterface*. It is not possible as *config_test* is using *config_dev* too.

This is the beginning of **services.yml** if it can help:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
```

**Any idea on how to autowire different cache system depending on the environment?**

### EDIT:

Here is the working configuration:

```
use Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface;

class MyApi
{
    /**
     * @var CacheItemPoolInterface
     */
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(CacheItemPoolInterface $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}
```

**config.yml**:

```
framework:
    # ...
    cache:
        pools:
            app.cache.api:
                default_lifetime: 3600
```

**services.yml**:

```
# ...
Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface:
    alias: 'app.cache.api'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though factory pattern is a good option to solve this kind of problem, normally you don't need to do that for Symfony cache system. Typehints `CacheItemPoolInterface` instead:

```
use Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface;

public function __construct(CacheItemPoolInterface $cache)
```

It automatically injects the current `cache.app` service depending on the active environment, so Symfony does the job for you!

Just make sure to configure the `framework.cache.app` for each environment config file:

```
# app/config/config_test.yml
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    #...
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.null

services:
    cache.adapter.null:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\NullAdapter
        arguments: [~] # small trick to avoid arguments errors on compile-time.
```

As `cache.adapter.null` service isn't available by default, you might need to define it manually.

Comment: Thanks! That was the answer I was looking for! But the default_lifetime of the pool doesn't seem to be working. Can you add that configuration please? `$item->expiresAfter(10)` works but I'd like to define a default value

Comment: The default_lifetime can be configure as well, check the [reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#default-lifetime).

Comment: I already tried that, but it's not taken into account. I'm using Filesystem.

Comment: If you can do a reproducer of the issue, please, report it to the [Symfony repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/new).

Comment: I will do it in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

In **Symfony 3.3+/4 and 2017/2019** you can omit any config dependency and keep full control of the behavior with **factory pattern**:

```
// AppBundle/Cache/CacheFactory.php

namespace AppBundle\Cache;

final class CacheFactory
{
    public function create(string $environment): CacheInterface
    {
        if ($environment === 'prod') {
            // do this
            return new ...;
        }

        // default 
        return new ...;
    }
}
```

And `services.yml` of course:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface:
        factory: 'AppBundle\Cache\CacheFactory:create'
        arguments: ['%kernel.environment%']
```

See more about service factory in [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html).

You can read more about this in my [Why Config Coding Sucks](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/02/14/why-config-coding-sucks/) post.

Comment: nice! +1 :) could you show the final `Api` service definition by using the factory method, thanks!

Comment: Will do in few hours, gotta go now.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know this was possible, I'll keep it in mind ;)