# How to disable Cache in Symfony 5.2?

Tags: symfony

How can I completely disable the cache in Symfony 5.2?

I use PHP config file (services.php) and **not** the yaml ones.
In the docs, I cannot find anything matching.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking why you have to manually run bin/console cache:clear after making changes to services.php?  It is annoying and I hope it will be fixed soon.  But it is basically just something to live with for now.

Answer (score 8):

Try configuring the two pools that are always enabled by default to use the `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\NullAdapter`

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.null
        system: cache.adapter.null

services:
    cache.adapter.null:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\NullAdapter
        arguments: [~] # small trick to avoid arguments errors on compile-time.
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#configuring-cache-with-frameworkbundle
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46898727/6127393

Comment: thanks for the small trick , had huge impact to solve problem :)

Comment: I'm using Symfony 6.2 and cache.adapter.null does no longer exists, instead I am using cache.adapter.array

Comment: Nice! I didn't need to add the line `arguments: [~]`, it's working without it (using symfony 6.3)