Disable Symfony cache
I want to deactivate the cache of a Symfony 6.4 application. The cache must be enabled or disabled according to an environment variable configured in the .env file.
I've read the Symfony cache documentation, but I can't find how to do this.
Could someone help me ?
I tried to configure pools and adapters according to Symfony documentation, but I did not manage to do it.
I wonder if there is a simple way to disable cache in development or testing mode for example.

Does this answer your question? How to disable Cache in Symfony 5.2?

Thanks a lot ! This help to disable cache, but I still can not disable it based on an environment variable.

probably in this question: Symfony services.yaml env custom param condition

Please add all solutions as answers, not as an edit to the original post

I cannot mark comments or answers as solutions because of my reputation. The edit is the only way I found to give my solution to all.

Setting a service configuration, based on the environment, should help. Replace when@dev with other environments, like when@test, if neccessary
when@dev:
    framework:
        cache:
            app: cache.adapter.null
            system: cache.adapter.null

services:
    cache.adapter.null:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\NullAdapter
        arguments: [~] # small trick to avoid arguments errors on compile-time.

(based on the work from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65865374)
